# Sort YouTube comment history by likes

Tags: youtube, comments

I was curious to see if there was any way I could see all of my YouTube comments, and there is, in the history section. I have a *lot* of comments, and after scrolling through them for a while, I wanted to see which one had accrued the most likes over the years. But then I realized that it doesn’t even show likes on that page. Is there any way I can see this information?

Comment: I would love to know that aswell.